# SQL Multiple Duplicate Row Detection

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm trying to determine a correct way to isolate rows within a table that have the same values in 2 columns.

There are two tables, one (Name) with the person's names and IDs, and the other one (Nation) with people's IDs and their nations.  I join the two tables with inner join, and now the new table columns consist of an ID, first name, last name, and nation.  If I want to find pairs of people who have the same last name and are from the same nation, why isn't

```
select ID, FName, LName, Nation
from (Name inner join Nation on Name.ID = Nation.ID)
group by Name, Nation
having count(Name) > 1 and count(Nation) > 1
```

working?

I'm aiming for the result to be a table with columns:

ID -------First--------------- Last ---------Nation

where the last names and nations will be identical pairs while first names will be different.

I feel like the group by part isnt appropriate, but is there even an alternate way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: So wait, Name TO Nation is a 1-to-1 relationship? i.e. one row in Name matches one row in Nation?

Comment: You need `SELECT LName, Nation FROM (...) GROUP BY LName, Nation HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Yes, every row in the joined table consists of a name and a nation, though many names can have the same nation in their nation column.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS SQL Server:

```
select
    *
from
(
    select 
        Name.*, 
        Nation.Nation, 
        cnt = count(*) over(partition by LName, Nation) 
    from Name
    join Nation on Nation.ID = Name.ID
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Name.ID, Name.FName, Name.LName, Nation.Nation
  FROM Name
  INNER JOIN Nation ON (Name.ID = Nation.ID)
) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Name.ID, Name.FName, Name.LName, Nation.Nation
  FROM Name
  INNER JOIN Nation ON (Name.ID = Nation.ID)
) b ON (a.LName = b.LName AND a.Nation = b.Nation)
WHERE a.ID < b.ID
```

Comment: Shouldn't `WHERE a.ID <> b.ID` be `WHERE a.ID < b.ID`? Otherwise you'll get two rows for each pair (i.e. Bob Smith from Namibia and Jane Smith from Namibia will show up as `('Bob','Smith','Namibia','Jane','Smith','Namibia')` and `('Jane','Smith','Namibia','Bob','Smith','Namibia')`

Comment: @Simon: Right. And `DISTINCT` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @SimonRigharts and ypercube, I adjusted the answer.

Comment: And you could simplify further by having only one `JOIN` to `Nation` and no subqueries.

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY, never would have thought of dupe table creation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As Simon Righarts hinted, something's not right with the design.

#### Scenario 1)

If a name can have **multiple nations**, you would have 3 tables implementing an n:m relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE name (name_id int, name text, ...);
CREATE TABLE nation (nation_id int, nation text, ...);
CREATE TABLE nationality (name_id int references name(name_id)
            ,nation_id int references nation(nation_id)
            ... );
```

Query for the scenario:

```
SELECT a.name_id, a.fname, a.lname, n.nation
  FROM name a
  JOIN nationality na USING (name_id)
  JOIN nation n USING (nation_id)
  JOIN (
   SELECT a.lname, na.nation_id
     FROM name a
     JOIN nationality na USING (name_id)
    GROUP BY 1,2
   HAVING count(*) > 1) x USING (lname, nation_id)
```

#### Scenario 2)

If a name can only have **one nation**, there would be a column `nation_id` in the table `name`:

```
CREATE TABLE name (name_id int
                  ,name text
                  ,nation_id int references nation(nation_id), ...);
CREATE TABLE nation (nation_id int, nation text, ...);
```

Query for this scenario:

```
SELECT a.name_id, a.fname, a.lname, n.nation
  FROM name a
  JOIN nation n USING (nation_id)
  JOIN (
   SELECT a.lname, a.nation_id
     FROM name a
    GROUP BY 1,2
   HAVING count(*) > 1) x USING (lname, nation_id);
```

All multiple occurrences are included here, not just "pairs" - assuming you meant that.

Your *actual* description doesn't fit either scenario.